# ways to get PHP class object to HTML user variable (PHP variable in HTML)

Tags: php

I want to get values of PHP DB class object to HTML side in easy ways so that i can echo simply. Ways to echo DB PHP class object to HTML(ex. like easy way in smart T).

Comment: are asking on how to pass objects into template files for html output?

Comment: Hi GEPPhoenix, yes i need to pass object in easy way. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of making the object visible to the template you can try passing it via

- [require](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [require_once](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

also take a look here

- [Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)